# Call a Google Apps Script that requires authorization in AJAX

Tags: javascript, ajax, google-apps-script, oauth-2.0, google-oauth

I need to access a Google Apps Script in AJAX that needs authorization from the user to send an email from his GMail Account.
For various reasons, I have to send that email from the Google Apps Script.

The call is made from my web application hosted on my server. I am also using Google Signin+ Authentication.
I tried to include gmail in the my web app authorization scopes, but it is not sufficient because my web App and my Google Apps Script are not the same entity for Google (not the same client_id).

I would like the whole thing to work as following :

1. The user authenticates on my web App on his Google Account
2. He clicks on a button to send an email
3. If he never gave the authorization to my Google Apps Script, the authorization popup is displayed
4. He grants permissions, he is *not* redirected to the Google Apps Script result page, but stays on my web app
5. The Google Apps Script sends the email, and returns something in JSONP to my Web App.

Is it possible to do that ?

I have thought of several solutions but I don't know how to make them work :

1. Is there a way to set the Google Apps Script' s client_id to be the
   same as my Web App ?
2. Or is there a way to create (& customize) the button which is automatically generated when I try to access a Google Apps Script to which I have not granted access, and display that button on my web app ?

I am stuck with this, any help much appreciated !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

None of your options are possible. You cant bypass that authorization screen in any way.
 Using the same clientid or scopes wont help you, at most that would authorize *your account* not the users account. Each user is an independent oauth flow with its own token saved by apps script.
However
If you must, its now possible to do it in a different way because:
1) apps script now supports (since feb 2014) implementing your own oauth2 flow.
See StateTokenBuilder/ScriptApp.getOAuthToken()/ScriptApp.newStateToken()

2) Google now offers an oauth2 gmail api (unveiled a few days ago at google I/O 2014)

with these two, you can make your own code to send emails using your own console project etc.

Comment: Ok, thank you for your answer. Can't I configure the popup generated by Google Apps Script like the one for my Web App ? I noticed in the HTML code that GAS associated a client_id with my script. However, in the Developers Console, no Client ID are created for my script.

Specifically, I would like to change the redirect_uri to "postmessage" so that the popup closes after the user grants access, but I get a no_registered_origin if I do that.

Comment: no, currently there is no way to access that console, its hidden

Comment: updated answer to describe an alternate way to do it.

Comment: Thank you kindly for taking the time to answer me, I'll look into what you have suggested.

Comment: Just to be sure about what you meant with "no way to access that console" : when I go to Resources > Advanced Googles Services in my Google Apps Script editor, there is a link to the Google Developers console for this project. I can add a client_id, and use it in a Google Signin+ button and define the scopes I want for this token (profile + gmail). It's almost working *except* when I tried to make my AJAX request to the GAS after the user has granted access on my web app, it still returns HTML with an "Authorize access" button (and thus, it causes an error).

Comment: So I thought the access I granted to the GAS with the client_id I manually created was not taken into account at all BUT, when I go the script page directly in a new tab, the prompt does not ask me for profile & gmail access, only for an "offline access". 
Meaning it's almost working if I could get the user to grant this access on my web app. However, whether I change `access_type` to `online`, or `offline`, the result is the same.
Did you know about this ? Is this the normal behaviour ?

Comment: Cool, I didn't know it was possible to get to the console project. Still, an ajax is impossible to do that, you need to provide a kink for the user ro click and do the oauth flow the first time. Ajax cant do that

Comment: @WaldoJeffers I have also noticed similar behaviour. Did you finally find a way to accomplish this?